# Java - Adding Asterisks between a user inputted string

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, input

I'm working on a class assignment with a few individual parts, which I have all done with the exception of this one. I need to get a string input from the user and create a loop (preferably a for loop) that inserts asterisks between each character. I'm completely stumped on this one so if someone could just give me some help to get started it would be appreciated.

Edit: I've come up with this so far

```
    } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
        System.out.print("Enter text here: ");
        String orig = input.nextLine();

        // To use for asterisk insertion
        int x = 1;
        int y = 2;

        for (int length = orig.length(); length > 0;) {
            orig = orig.substring(0,x) + "*" + orig.substring(y);
            x = x + 2;
            y = y + 2;
        }

    }
```

It compiles just fine but when I test it and enter some text it comes up with 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you running into trouble?  Also, why "(preferably a for loop)"?  Why does it matter what kind of loop you use?

Comment: It's a loop assignment. We need to use one while, do-while, and for loop. The for loop is the only one I haven't used. I know I need to use the .substring(x,y) method but I'm not sure how to set it up so that the loop inserts asterisks between each character of the string that the user enters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a for loop on the characters of the String (see below), but I would just do this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?<=.)(?=.)", "*");
```

The regex in the search parameter matches the point between any two characters, achieved by using a look-behind and a look-ahead, each asserting that there's a character there.

---

If you must use a loop, the *simplest* code is probably:

```
String result = input.isEmpty() ? "" : input.substring(0, 1);
for (int i = 1; i < input.length(); i++)
    result += "*" + input.charAt(i);
```

The somewhat complicated first line caters for the edge case of the user entering a blank. The for loop already caters for blank input, because the terminating condition will always be false for blank, so it won't iterate at all.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a loop for this. Thank you though.

Comment: See edited answer for an elegant (IMHO) loop solution. If you use the code, make sure you thoroughly understand it, so this is still a learning experience.